# Multiple JOINs too complex

Tags: mysql

This has become more complex than I can follow. I have modified this query from another post here and now I need to add another join, but it's not working.

Here is the current query in MySQL:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT *,
                @rn := IF(@prev = class, @rn + 1, 1) AS rn,
                @prev := class
               FROM HeatWaveData
               JOIN
                (SELECT @prev := NULL, @rn := 0) AS vars
                ORDER BY class, score DESC)
               AS T1
               WHERE rn <= 3
                 AND score > 0
                 AND dsqreason = ''
                 AND class <> ''
```

Now I need to `JOIN (SELECT * FROM Awards WHERE active ON Awards.award = HeatWaveData.award)`
but it fails with errors. I've tried several changes and different things but keep getting errors.

Here is my updated query and error:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT *,
                @rn := IF(@prev = class, @rn + 1, 1) AS rn,
                @prev := class
               FROM HeatWaveData
               JOIN
                (SELECT @prev := NULL, @rn := 0) AS vars
                ORDER BY class, score DESC)
               AS T1
             LEFT JOIN
               (SELECT * FROM Awards WHERE active = '1'
                ON Awards.award = T1.award) AS T2
             WHERE rn <= 3
                 AND score > 0
                 AND dsqreason = ''
                 AND class <> ''
```

Error:

```
error: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near
'ON Awards.award = T1.award) AS T2 WHERE rn <= 3 AN' at line 11
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try to replace your sub-select with a "normal" join:

**old:**

```
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT * FROM Awards WHERE active = '1'
ON Awards.award = T1.award) AS T2
```

**new:**

```
LEFT JOIN Awards AS T2
ON T2.award = T1.award AND T2.active = '1'
```

Comment: I worked on that for a while. Thank you. It was just a bit over my head